# Controlling state of Sony Camera qx100 (turning on, off) programmatically?

Tags: camera, sony

I would like to know if it is possible to turn on the sony camera dsc-qx100 (or qx10) programmatically or if it is mandatory to turn it on manually ?

Also, is it possible to control the period before the camera turns off ?
My idea is to be able to switch between two cameras and it seems that if I don't connect to one for a while, it will turning off automatically (My test on playMemories app gives me four minutes before it turns off).
Is there a way to avoid that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Controlling the power state is not possible programatically.
2. This is not controllable either.

Answer (score 0):

> (My test on playMemories app gives me four minutes before it turns
>   off). Is there a way to avoid that ?

On some models it is possible to programmatically change autoPowerOff time or to deactivate it. Look for setAutoPowerOff.